# Parenthesis while using subfig and autoref

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, subfloats

I would like to use `subfig` while using the `autoref` package. I have added the line

```
\usepackage[listofformat=subparens,subrefformat=parens,labelformat=parens]{subfig}
\newcommand{\subfigureautorefname}{\figureautorefname}
```

to my master tex file. The purpose of adding these lines was to see *Figure 1(a)* instead of *Figure 1a* each time I reference a subfigure. I wish to see the parenthesis. The problem is if use `\autoref{fig:ABC}` instead of seeing *Figure 1(a)* I see *Figure 1a*. However if I

Comment: It looks like you didn't finish your question. Ideally, please post a Minimal Working example: http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that

Answer (score 8):

You could use `\renewcommand\thesubfigure{(\alph{subfigure})}`, as shown below.

```
\documentclass{article}

% subfig setup
\usepackage[labelformat=simple]{subfig}
\renewcommand\thesubfigure{(\alph{subfigure})}
\newcommand{\subfigureautorefname}{\figureautorefname}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
 \subfloat[]{
 \centering
 \rule{30pt}{20pt}
 \label{fig:firstpic}
 }
 \hfill
 \subfloat[]{
 \centering
 \rule{30pt}{20pt}
 \label{fig:secondpic}
 }
 \caption{}
\end{figure}

\autoref{fig:firstpic} and \autoref{fig:secondpic}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that `\autoref` is from the `\hyperref` package.