# (Solved, New) Parenthesis while using subfig and autoref

Tags: brackets, subfig, autoref

MWE first.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[subrefformat=simple,labelformat=simple]{subfig}

%\newcommand{\subfigureautorefname}{\figureautorefname}
%\renewcommand\thesubfigure{(\alph{subfigure})}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\subfloat[]{\label{a}\qquad}
\caption{}
\end{figure}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
&Result\\\hline
ref&\ref{a}\\\hline
subref&\subref{a}\\\hline
autoref&\autoref{a}\\\hline
subref*&\subref*{a}\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

I use package `subfig` to create subfigures and I want to use both `\subref` in captions and `\autoref` in the context.

**My desired output of `\subref` and `\autoref` are `(a)` and `Figure 1(a)` respectively**, but I'm not able to achieve them at the same time. I have tried different options for `subfig` and the solution [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30846/parenthesis-while-using-subfig-and-autoref)(where this question title came from). I also tried to create a new command but failed because I know little about macro or something like that.

**Edit:** Thanks for @Mico 's solution using package `subcaption`! I prefer to stick to `subfig` because it's exhausting to edit all floats in my document.

So I didn't check the `subfig` manual carefully enough. There are 3 options for typesetting subfloat labels. `labelformat` sets the label displayed under each subfloat. `listofformat` sets the output of `\subref`. `subrefformat` sets
the output of `\subref*`.

In my case, I only need to add `listofformat=subsimple` to get rid of the extra pair of parens in `\subref`, then I could use `\renewcommand\thesubfigure{(\alph{subfigure})}` to add the parens to `\autoref`. Full solution below. I didn't notice `listofformat` because its name can't seem to do anything, compared to `subrefformat`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[listofformat=subsimple,labelformat=simple]{subfig}

\newcommand{\subfigureautorefname}{\figureautorefname}
\renewcommand\thesubfigure{(\alph{subfigure})}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\subfloat[]{\label{a}\qquad}
\caption{}
\end{figure}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
&Result\\\hline
subref&\subref{a}\\\hline
autoref&\autoref{a}\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Does it have to be a solution that involves the `subfig` package, or are you willing to entertain a solution based on the `subcaption` package?

Comment: You have to load `hyperref` last

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Links are not reliable, it can become death after while, so please provide all relevant code in your question only.

Comment: @DG' - The change you suggest (plus uncommenting two lines in the OP's code) doesn't achieve the OP's formatting objectives.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a `subcaption`-based solution, which works with both `\autoref` and `\cref` (provided by the `cleveref` package).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % remove 'demo' option in real document
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{subcaption}
\renewcommand\thesubfigure{(\alph{subfigure})}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=simple}

\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\subcaptionbox{First subfigure\label{a}}{\includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{figa}}%
\qquad
\subcaptionbox{Second subfigure\label{b}}{\includegraphics[width=0.25\textwidth]{figa}}
\caption{A figure with two subfigures}
\end{figure}

\begin{tabular}{ll}
\textbackslash ref    &\ref{a}    \\
\textbackslash subref &\subref{a} \\
\textbackslash subref*&\subref*{a}\\
\textbackslash autoref&\autoref{a}\\
\textbackslash Cref   &\Cref{a}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! What if I want to change the refname like how I set the `figureautorefname` in hyperref? Optional argument for `label` may work, but I have hundreds of figures in my document and I don't want to edit every label. Sorry that I didn't include this information in the OP because I didn't expect the solution to not use the `autorefname` set by `hyperref`.

Comment: @putianyi888 - I'm not sure I understand your follow-up question. (The final sentence of your follow-up question contains a double, or maybe even triple, negative. Moreover, my answer doesn't modify `\figureautorefname` at all.)  For sure, just use `\renewcommand` to change the definition of `\figureautorefname`. E.g., `\renewcommand{\figureautorefname}{Figura}`.